# filter with multiple regexmatch?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

**my spreadsheet link with edit authorized - feel free to test any formula**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iY0p3_mdOfrjtBy9HPskzudf27m1mh_hApecsn0KW4A/edit#gid=1268421551

***please look at the country that has statename such as P26-P38***

---

I have 2 sheets - one is main sheet and another is named 'articles'

**MAIN SHEET**

[image]

**ARTICLES**

[image]

MAIN SHEET > on column P > I need to show the maximum date value located in column 'F' [articles!F:F] 
from 'articles' sheet by finding any rows on column 'B' of 'articles' [articles!B:B]
that contains the number from column 'M' of 'Main sheet'  [main!M:M]
so I use this formula

> =IFERROR(MAX(filter(articles!F:F,regexmatch(","&articles!B:B,","&M58&","))))

and its working fine

but then I also need to find state name which is located in 'column E of articles'[articles!E:E]

like in the screenshot above I need to find 'Alberta' for Canada 
as you can see the state name will come after '-' and follow by ':'

So it need to match both conditions and return the date

I don't know how can I define it in the formula 'regexmatch' and combine it together with the formula that I already have

I tried this but doesn't work

> =IFERROR(MAX(filter(articles!F:F,regexmatch(","&articles!B:B,","&M58&","),articles!E:E,"-"&"
>   "&K58&":")

anyone please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
=IFERROR(MAX(filter(articles!F:F,regexmatch(articles!B:B&articles!E:E, M59&K58&":"))))
```

If not, please share a copy of your spreadsheet with editing rights.

EDIT: after seeing the data, try (e.g. in P26)

```
=IFERROR(MAX(filter(articles!F:F,regexmatch(","&articles!B:B,","&M26&","), regexmatch(articles!E:E,K26))))
```

Drag up or down as far as needed.

Comment: tried that, doesn't work. I added the link of spreadsheet on the top of the question ,please test at P26-P38.thanks

Comment: Updated formula. Please try.